# Python Error SSL: ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:726)

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, openssl, python-requests

i'm trying to get the SNI from a (IP, destport 443) with python 2.7.15 and i'm using the last version of OpenSSL and the ssl module.

Here there is my code:

```
import OpenSSL as OSsl #This two modules are imported for the only purpose of getting the SNI using function defined by us down here getSNI
import ssl



ip = "52.85.25.17"
dport = "443"


#With this function we get the Server Name Identification for the trasmissions with Secure Socket Layer identified by the port 443. We only care about the destinationIP and the destinationPort

def getSNI(ip, dport):
    if dport != "443":
        commonName = "Not SSL"
        print commonName
    else:   
        server_certificate = ssl.get_server_certificate((ip, dport))

        x509 = OSsl.crypto.load_certificate(OSsl.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, server_certificate) #x509 is referred to the standard used for PKI (Public Key Infrastructure) used in this case for ciphering our informations about certificate

#FILETYPE_PEM serializes data to a Base64-Encoded

    #getting the informations about Certificate

        certInfo = x509.get_subject()
        commonName = certInfo.commonName
        print (commonName) 
    return commonName


getSNI(ip,dport)
```

This works, but for the address specified (in the snippet of code i posted here) I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getSNI.py", line 31, in <module>
    getSNI(ip,dport)
  File "getSNI.py", line 17, in getSNI
    server_certificate = ssl.get_server_certificate((ip, dport))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 1023, in get_server_certificate
    with closing(context.wrap_socket(sock)) as sslsock:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 369, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 617, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 846, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:726)
```

I have all modules and packages upgraded, i read a lot of issues about this topic and i don't know how to solve this problem

Edit1: Executing whois I found that this IpAddress is connected to Amazon, so are there any particular issues about Amazon and SNI?

Comment: This seems like an handshake failure. Note that SSLv3 is obsolete, it's highly likely that the latest versions of SSL do not try to use it by default and you have to tell them to accept obsolete crypto for this to work. Or the issue might be with the server. Did you try to specify `ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3` when calling `get_server_certificate`? From python3.5 the default is TLS.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.15rc. I tried to set ssl_version = ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3 and the traceback is "'module' object has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_SSLv3'
"  Should I to install anything else o change this directly in the module library?

Comment: Are you sure that the server supports SSLv3? Try to specify `PROTOCOL_TLS` instead.

Comment: tried with PROTOCOL_TLS and nothing changes. What if I can't be sure about what server supports?

Comment: *"...get the SNI from a (IP..."* - this makes no sense. The SNI needs to be provided by the client to the server so that the server can decide which certificate to provide. There can be multiple valid SNI on the same IP address. You cannot query the possible SNI from the client side. Your code only checks the certificate returned if no SNI is given, which might result in an error or in returning some default certificate which might but does not need to have anything to do with the certificates provided when SNI is used.

Comment: So, are you telling me that it is impossible as Client?

Answer (score 1):

The point of SNI is that there could exists several domains which are resolved to concrete IP address. So, the IP you provided (`52.85.25.17`) is the one of such addresses. Server couldn't decide which domain's cert you are requesting, so it terminates the connection with error.

*Appendix 1. Catching SSLError exceptions*

You can catch `ssl.SSLError` this way:

```
try:
    server_certificate = ssl.get_server_certificate((ip, dport))
    ...
except ssl.SSLError as e:
    common_name = "Handshake Failed"
```

Comment: In case of using SNI you should specify domain name, not an IP address. You couldn't get list of available hostnames by design. To prevent crashing just catch `ssl.SSLError` exception.

Comment: May you post an example? For istance Could I put the first part under try: and then except ssl.SSLError return me "Handshake Failed"?

Comment: Sorry, just rereaded your comment. Yes, you are correct in your understanding.

Comment: Edit: I did, so thank you, for the moment I'll use this solution, I'm keep waiting for any other suggests if you all have

Comment: Any updated ideas on this issue? I have a similar case and my code crashed even if I have ```verify=false``` in my ```requests.get()``` call.